# Replicação no postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql

Boa noite pessoal. Estou tentando fazer um replicação no postgresql 9.4. Eu fiz as configurações exatamente igual a dos arquivos `postgres.conf` e `pg_hba.conf` no *master* e no *slave*, só que quando eu derrubo o *master* o *slave* desconecta. Eu gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma coisa a respeito. No *slave* eu coloquei o seguinte código no `recovery.conf`:

```sql
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host = IPMASTER port = MASTER user=TESTE password=TESTE1'
restore_command = 'cp / PGDATA / archive /% f "% p"' 
trigger_file =  '/tmp/psql.trigger'
```

Gostaria de saber porque a conexão cai.